# Google authentication in Blazor. Both Asp.net Core hosted and MAUI

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth, blazor-webassembly, maui, maui-blazor

I'm developing a Blazor WebAssembly App.
I'll host it both on Asp.net core and MAUI App (Android).
I want to implement Google authentication.
The code should work in both environments.
I don't want to store user id and secrets on the app but only on backend.

I tried Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

I don't find a clear unique solution. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check this article about the [Google external login setup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-the-google-oauth-20-client-id-and-secret). This provides the method to login the application by using the Google authentication.

This article also provides the information about the [Secret Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which can store the id and the secrets. Production secrets shouldn't be used for development or test. Secrets shouldn't be deployed with the app. So you do not need to worry about the password leakage problem.